# Python library for large scale convex optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, python

I'm trying to find a library for convex optimization in python which can handle a large amount of variables and constraints.

My problem is in the form

$$
\min p^T \cdot q + |c| \\
\text{lower bound} \leq q \leq \text{upper bound} \\
\text{lower bound} \leq c \leq \text{upper bound} \\
Aq + Bc = d \\
\text{lower bound} \leq Rq \leq \text{upper bound}
$$

Where $p, d$ are vectors and $A, B$  are sparse matrices and $q, c$ are variables. $R$ is a special matrix which might be the cause of my issue.

$$
Rq = \\
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1 \\
q_2 \\
q_3 \\
q_4  \\
q_1 + q_5 \\
q_2 + q_6 \\
q_3 + q_7\\
q_4 + q_8 \\
q_1 + q_5 +q_9 \\
q_2 + q_6 + q_{10} \\
q_3 + q_7 + q_{11} \\
q_4 + q_8 + q_{12} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{k=0}^n q_{4k+1} \\
\sum_{k=0}^n q_{4k+2} \\
\sum_{k=0}^n q_{4k+3} \\
\sum_{k=0}^n q_{4k+4} 
\end{pmatrix} \\
=\\
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &
\end{pmatrix}q
$$

code

```
from cvxopt.modeling import variable, op, sum 
q = variable(numb_prod, 'q')
c = variable(numb_capacity, 'c')
prod_price = price_purchase_power.trans() * q

problem = op(sum(prod_price) + 1e-6*sum(abs(c)), [constraints])
problem.solve(format='sparse', solver='glpk', options= 
{'glpk'{'msg_lev':'GLP_MSG_OFF'}})
```

error

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns) File "", line 489, in q, c, total_cost_x, water_values, list_numb_of_capacity_variables = solution(demand, price_purchase_power, supply) File "", line 391, in solution test = problem.solve(format='sparse', solver='glpk', options={'glpk':{'msg_lev':'GLP_MSG_OFF'}}) File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 2600, in solve t = self._inmatrixform(format) File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 2479, in _inmatrixform for v in variables: vmap[v] = x[vslc[v]] File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 240, in getitem return (+self).getitem(key) File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 931, in getitem f._linear = self._linear[l] File "C:\Users\OsRas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\modeling.py", line 1385, in getitem for v,c in iter(self._coeff.items()): OverflowError: **Python int too large to convert to C long**

Currently I'm having 108575 variables which is too large for cvxopt. I was hopping running an optimization which can handle the amount of variables in the millions...

Is there any library that can handle that? Or does one need to look into another language?

I can sacrifice some accuracy and make this problem LP by removing $|c|$ if that opens up other possibilities.

I've asked this question on stackoverflow as well. But perhaps there is a better auidience here.

**Edit**
As the problem is formulated now we have

$\dim(A) = 26058 \times 73831 $ with average three $1$:s per row, rest zero, upper triangle.

$\dim(B) =26058 \times 34744$ with average of three elements per row, $1$:s and $-1$:s, rest zero, elements around diagonal and some one the diagonal.

$\dim(R) = 17280 \times 73831$

Comment: Which norm does $|c|$ denote? For most norms, this problem is not even convex.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek elementwise absolute value. Can also be elementwise square

Comment: You mean $+|c|$ in the objective then? Or max instead of min? Otherwise non-convex.

Comment: Well anyhow, assuming you somehow really have a convex problem, then you can check CVXPY and see the list of solvers available there, pretty much all of them will be able to handle your problem, and the easiest will be to implement it in CVXPY and then plug in any solver you want. https://www.cvxpy.org/install/index.html

Comment: Yes! I do mean $+|c|$. Thanks I will look into it @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: No problem. So you can choose between any LP solver (for 1-norm, i.e. sum of absolute values) or QP and SOCP solvers (for 2-norm i.e. sums of squares).

Comment: I dont understand though how this will make a difference. With CVXOPT i've tried both mosek and glpk and they fail with complaining with the number of variables. @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: Can you say a bit more about $A$ and $B$? What is the number of rows? What is the sparsity pattern?

Comment: please see edit @LinAlg

Comment: If you have a big interesting problem where Mosek struggles it will be very welcome to communicate with Mosek support. Probably your problem suffers from some numerical issues because just having 1e+6 variables is not a problem in itself, especially with so sparse matrices as here.

Comment: My bad. The problem isnt necessary with the solver, but with the package cvxopt. My error "Python int too large to convert to C long" comes from inside the cvxopt package and not the solver. @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: In cvxopt, you can provide your own function to solve the KKT equations, exploiting whatever special structure is present in your problem. I view this as being the key feature of cvxopt. Have you tried that?https://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#exploiting-structure

Comment: I have not tried that. From the error "Python int too large to convert to C long" it seems to be some cvxopt issue

Comment: If you want to handle an amount of variables in the millions, I also recommend considering a first-order algorithm such as ADMM / Douglas-Rachford or the Chambolle-Pock algorithm (especially if you only need a few digits of precision in your solution). With an interior point method, for a problem of that size, I would say that you would most likely need to exploit whatever special problem structure you have by implementing your own solver for the KKT equations.

Comment: @littleO I just need 10^-1 precision

Comment: Oh ok, in that case one of the first-order methods I mentioned seems definitely worth considering. Boyd's article about [proximal algorithms](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/prox_algs.html) is one good resource for such methods.

Comment: @littleO Have you noticed that I updated my constraints? Just to make sure that you spend time recommendating with lack of information, sorru

Comment: @Olba12 Those constraints are ok for proximal algorithms such as ADMM. By the way, I'd be curious to hear what this is for / what the application is.

Comment: You seem to have some experience with cvxopt. It's not that the formulation of the problem is inefficient? I tried the same code on linux and got the same error msg. I'd like to make sure before I spend time implementing another solution. The problem is a supply/demand problem. Imagine having some factories which can produce $q$ in different countries. Each country has its own demand. Price to produce in factories varies each hour. You also have the possibility to transfer quantites between countries with capacities $c$.@littleO

Answer (score 0):

On Stackoverflow you [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66116253/python-library-for-large-scale-convex-optimization) that $|c|$ means $||c||_1$, so the problem can be made linear. I can think of two solution methods.

The first one is to use an interior point algorithm. Due to the size of the problem, the location of the $1$s is important. If either $AA^T + BB^T$ or
$$\begin{pmatrix}A^TA & O \\ O & B^TB\end{pmatrix}$$
has a sparse Cholesky factorization (for example, it can be row/column permuted to an arrow matrix), this approach can be memory efficient and fast. You could try CPLEX or Gurobi. They should tell you the number of nonzeros in the cholesky factor.

The second option is to use [ADMM](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Eyc5/ele522_optimization/lectures/ADMM.pdf). You could solve the subproblems in cvxpy or use a [specialized package](https://github.com/bungun/pogs-python). I have never had much luck with ADMM, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I didnt realize that the locations of the $1$:s where important. Ive updated with the location of these. $A$ is upper triangular and $B$ have the elements around the diagonal

Comment: I also forgot to tell about one constraint. Post has been updated.